# Preencher apenas um campo

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho 6 filtros em um formulário... Apenas um filtro pode ser preenchido. Já tentei usar um XOR, usar uma flag, mas não da certo:

```
// rgn20180711 TrixDes : inclusão de campos que permitem buscar o codigo pelo nome
if ($fp["Param.CodPadEdicao"]!="" xor $fp["Param.CodDominio"]!="" xor $fp["Param.Tabela"]!="" 
xor $fp["Param.CodFuncional"]!="" xor $fp["Param.CodCampo"]!="" xor (($fp["Param.NumLanIni"] =! "") && ($fp["Param.Tipo"] =! "")))
    MessImg("Apenas uma das informações devem ser preenchidas. Caso seja o código, o tipo é necessário!", MESSERRO, true);

if ($fp["Param.CodPadEdicao"]!="") //Padrão de Edição
{   
    $fp["Param.NumLanIni"] = $fp["Param.CodPadEdicao"]; 
    $fp["Param.Tipo"] = "P";
}
if ($fp["Param.Tabela"]!="")//tabela
{   
    $fp["Param.NumLanIni"] = $fp["Param.Tabela"];
    $fp["Param.Tipo"] = "A";
}
if ($fp["Param.CodCampo"]!="")//Campo de Tabela
{   
    $fp["Param.NumLanIni"] = $fp["Param.CodCampo"]; 
    $fp["Param.Tipo"] = "T";
}
if ($fp["Param.CodDominio"]!="") //Domínio
{   
    $fp["Param.NumLanIni"] = $fp["Param.CodDominio"]; 
    $fp["Param.Tipo"] = "D";
}
if ($fp["Param.CodFuncional"]!="")//Funcionalidade
{   
    $fp["Param.NumLanIni"] = $fp["Param.CodFuncional"]; 
    $fp["Param.Tipo"] = "F";
}
```

ele somente da certo se eu não usar esses dois campos que precisam necessariamente serem preenchidos juntos:

```
(($fp["Param.NumLanIni"] =! "") && ($fp["Param.Tipo"] =! ""))
```

no caso eu teria que testar se mais de um campo estiver preenchido retorno um erro dizendo que apenas um campo pode estar preenchido.
O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar `elseif`?

Comment: um elseif em cada teste? se eu preencher mais de um campo o vetor vai voltar preenchido pode entrar em um elseif indesejado! no caso o primeiro que vier no vetor!

Comment: o correto seria o elseif, que atenderia sua necessidade pois caso ele ache algum deles iria parar e preencher.

Comment: compeendi perfeitamente @Otto.. entretanto nao está sendo tratado o erro... ele vai pegar o que vier primeiro no vetor e não vai impedir o usuario de preencher mais de um campo!

Comment: Já pensou em fazer isso com javascript ? preencheu um campo limpa o resto heheheh

Comment: Seria mais fácil com certeza... mas não tenho permissão mexer no código JS =/
Os mesmos filtros são usados em varias funcionalidades do sistema!

Comment: Porque não resolve isso com JavaScript e jQuery? Utilize uma lógica aonde, quando um filtro for preenchido/selecionado, os demais inputs sejam desabilitados.

Comment: Galera... como não posso mexer no JS, abordei de forma diferente... fiz consultas com todos os campos preenchidos e retornei todas elas! Obrigado pela força!